# SQL Server Always Encrypted Limitation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add always encrypted to my DB table. But its not allowed to add. I can't select any encryption type. Is there any reason. I'm using SQL Server 2016.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed previous steps before adding this to a specific column.

Perhaps you need to generate the keys to be used or setting up encryption settings. [(Always Encrypted definition)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

You might use the [ALways Encrypted Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)